# Is it possible to execute code when a user (ctrl+c) terminates JVM from command line?

Tags: java

Like the title says, is it possible to use JVM termination as a trigger to execute "clean up" code in a Java application?

Answer (score 0):

Yes,you can write your clean up logic in shut down hook up.